# Is it possible to use gcloud credentials for calling GCP API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I noticed that if I use the `gcloud` command, it creates in my home directory the file `.google_libcloud_auth.${GCE_PROJECT}` that contains information such as (formatted):

```
{
  "access_token": "....",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expire_time": "2018-05-21T12:07:23Z",
  "expires_in": 3600,
  "refresh_token": "..."
}
```

Is it possible to use this file as credential to access the GCP API? If so, is there any guide on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question, yes it is very much possible to access Google Cloud services with a JSON access token such as the one created for the gcloud SDK.

Nonetheless, depending on your application, other access methods could be more convenient. Seeing your main interest is using GCP APIs, I would recommend you to read the documentation about accessing using [API Keys](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys).

If you would like to explore all the possible Authentication methods I can recommend to start with the [authentication overview](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/) documentation page.